# multiple plots on Infographics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I trying create a Infographisc report, but I can not use multiple chart on this report.

```
dat <- get.ohlc.yahoo('AAPL', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-31')
dat1 <- get.ohlc.yahoo('GOOG', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-31')

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(date, adjusted)) + geom_line() + theme_minimal() + 
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(date, volume)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_minimal() + 
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))

p3 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(date, adjusted)) + geom_line() + theme_minimal() + 
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())

p4 <- ggplot(dat1,aes(date, volume)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_minimal() + 
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

When I use:

```
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(4, 3)))

pdf("plot.pdf")
grid::grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(4, 1)))
print(p1, vp=vplayout(1,1))
print(p2, vp=vplayout(2,1))
print(p3, vp=vplayout(3,1))
print(p4, vp=vplayout(4,1))

dev.off()
```

code workin well, but when I wont create multiple plots on report plots don't look good as before:

```
pdf("plot.pdf")
grid::grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 1)))
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1, heights = c(2, 1))
grid.arrange(p3, p4, ncol = 1, heights = c(2, 1))

dev.off()
```

Comment: I honestly can't tell what the problem is. You seem to have working code? Your example isn't reproducible.

Comment: The problem is in the second code, I can not put multiple plots on the report.

Comment: `grid.arrange()` is (in essence) a wrapper for `grid.layout()` so I don't understand why you're trying to combine the two. Use one or the other.

Comment: I changed the code using `grid.layout`, but the report still does not look like I wanted. Has anyone tried to make a professional report in R like this one: [link]https://plot.ly/dash/gallery/goldman-sachs-report/